# How can I quickly detect irrelevant Keywords suggested by Google Keyword Planner?

Tags: seo, negative-seo, google-keyword-tool

Even if I provide focused seeds to Google Keyword Planner, it usually returns some irrelevant keywords.

I want to quickly detect and remove them. Do I have to check every suggested keyword? Sometimes it's really time consuming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the Keyword Planner's filter options?

The filtering feature, provides 2 options for you:

**Negative Keywords:**
As you scroll through the generated Keywords, simply enter any Keywords you do not want to appear, within the 'Negative Keyword' list.  In doing so, it will remove any Keywords, which contain the Negative Keyword, from the list.

Keyword Text:
If you select the Filter option, you will see a Pop up box, as follows:

[image: Keyword Text]

You can simply enter a word or phrase you want to only appear in the generated list of Keyword.  For example, your list may contain:

- Red Apples
- Red Fruit
- Bunch of Apples
- Apples for Sale
- Yellow Bananas

If you only want Keywords to contain 'Apples', then the list will filter, to only show:

- Red Apples
- Bunch of Apples
- Apples for Sale

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, the example you gave is rather simplistic, my objective is to know how SEO professionals handle CSV files (especially huge ones) to detect all the possible negative keywords (or their stems). Do I have to read it entirely? Is there an approach that will save me some time even if it's manual?

Comment: Are you saying that a `.csv` file has been provided to you, in order to manage or have you generated the Keywords yourself, via Google's Keyword Planner and downloaded the Report as a `.csv` file?

Comment: I usually provide some KWs seeds to GKP, then download the CSV file of all the generated ideas, the next step is to clean this file from unrelated/irrelevant KWs with Excel and its filtering capabilities, this task is really time consuming and for that reason I am looking for some tips and best practices.

Comment: @Simohammedhttc: So it is a Spreadsheet, generated from your own GKP Research?!  In that case, why not follow my answer?  If not anything else, it at least keeps your `.csv` file to a minimum.  After all, why would you want to download unwanted Keywords, when these can be filtered out beforehand? :-)

Comment: Please, bear with me, you said "why would you want to download unwanted Keywords", that's the main issue of the question, how to quickly spot and remove these unwanted KWs, Finally, I think I have to examine the entire file for intruders, sometimes you may want to ignore a KW not because it's a negative KW but because it's too vague or something else, imagine if I am looking for "kitchen decoration", the KW "Kitchen" is too vague so I have to omit it, so quick filtering with Negative KWs won't help in this situation which entails a lot of examination work.

Comment: @Simohammedhttc:  When are using the Keyword Tool/Spreadsheet, do you have a list of the Keywords, you want filtered?

Comment: I provide some seeds, I download the raw CSV file that contains in average 700 .. 800 records, it takes me a while to check them in order to clean it, and for that reason I am asking if SEO/SEA professionals have some tips or best practices that may simplify this time consuming step.

Comment: @Simohammedhttc:  Another option could be to generate the Keywords, within the Keyword Planner, as you normally would.  Once generated, head over to the Keyword tab and enter all the negative Keywords as phrase matches.  This would then set all Keywords, with the Negative keyword in, to zero traffic.  Then download the `.csv` file as you would, normally.  Once downloaded, arrange the 'Traffic Volume' column, in ascending order.  In doing so, all the zero traffic Keywords (those containing your Negative Keyword(s)), will be grouped together.  You can then batch delete those Keywords.